# .htaccess URL rewriting does not work

Tags: .htaccess

I wrote this code into my .htaccess file, but it seems not to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category/test.php?name=$1 [L]
```

When writing http://example.com/z.html it automatically redirects me to 404 file.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and try your rules this way.

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /category/test.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did mistake at this sentence "RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category/test.php?name=$1 [L]", after replacing it with your's it works like a charm :)